# Trying to compile code - Could not find or load main class a

Tags: java, netbeans, compiler-errors, program-entry-point

So I've looked up many tutorials on how to compile code. I've tried to follow all of them. But I keep getting that error. Here's my code:

```
package ytho;

public class a {
    public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("ytho");
    }


}
```

And here's what I put for my manifest.txt:

```
Main-Class: a
```

I've also tried putting it as `Main-Class: .a` and `Main-Class: ytho.a`, to no avail.
I'm sorry that this is a duplicate, but all other tutorials on here haven't worked for me. So, I decided to finally ask myself. Help would be greatly appreciated. And if you need more information, let me know, but I may be late to reply.

Comment: Oh, yes, just forgot to put that in the question.

Comment: How exactly are you creating your JAR?

Comment: Are you using an IDE or the command line to create your JAR file? If you use the command line? What is the exact command? Also what directory are you in when you do it? And what is the directory structure of your project?

Comment: I'm using the cmd to create it. I convert the .java file into a .class file with `javac -d ../classes a.java` and that goes into the folder with my manifest.txt that says `Main-Class: a`. I go into the directory and run the command `jar -cvmf manifest.txt ytho.jar a.class`. That converts it into a jar file, but when I try to run it using `java -jar ytho.jar` I get the error `Error: Could not find or load main class a`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets do it step my step:

1. Create a folder with your package name
2. Rename your `a` class to `A` since java uses Capitals on the first letter (this is stylistic)
3. Compile your file `javac ytho/A.java`
4. Create the jar
   `jar cvfm MyJarName.jar MANIFEST.MF *`

Here is what my directory looks like

```
.
├── MANIFEST.MF
├── MyJarName.jar
└── ytho
    ├── A.class
    └── A.java
```

Here is the content of the Manifest

```
Main-Class: ytho.A
```

And run it like so:

```
$: java -jar MyJarName.jar
```

which print out

```
ytho
```

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest, you are missing the package in your classname:

```
Main-Class: ytho.a
```

See this link for more details: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html

Also, you should not name your class with all lowercase (or a single character for that matter).Call it something meaninful like JarTest.class or something

Comment: I've tried `Main-Class: ytho.a`, but it hasn't worked.